# Dropping temp tables in sql server with pyobdc

Tags: pyodbc

I am trying to check a temp table exists and if so, drop it in SQL Server with pyodbc. The query works in management studio, but in python I get the error

> Previous SQL was not a query

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('APP=MyApp;DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};SERVER=powerapp6-WRON;DATABASE=ICP;DSN=myserver;Trusted_Connection=yes')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cnxn.commit()

for mc in range(0,3,1):
    speardata =  (""" if object_id('tempdb..#tempCSID') is not null
    begin
        drop table #tempCSID
    end
    create table #tempCSID (csid int)
    insert into #tempCSID (csid)
    select top 500 [CSID]
    from  [ICP].[dbo].[CSID]
    order by newid()
    SELECT [ICP].[dbo].[CSunit_L].[CSID] ,[Nitrogen] ,[Incorp0] ,[Incorp200] ,[yield] ,[xdays] ,[accum_rain] ,[avg_maxt]
          ,[avg_mint] ,[accum_radn] ,[xgdays] ,[accum_g_rain] ,[avg_g_maxt] ,[avg_g_mint] ,[accum_g_radn] ,[effrain_g] ,[xshdays]
          ,[accum_sh_rain] ,[avg_sh_maxt] ,[avg_sh_mint] ,[accum_sh_radn] ,[effrain_sh]
    FROM [ICP].[dbo].[CSunit_L]
    inner join #tempCSID 
    on [ICP].[dbo].[CSunit_L].[CSID] = #tempCSID.csid and [ICP].[dbo].[CSunit_L].[Nitrogen] < 201
    """)
    ndata =  np.array(cursor.execute(speardata).fetchall() )
```

I was wondering if it is something to do with the cnxn settings in the first two lines as the `tempdb` is in a different location to the `ICP` database?

Answer (score 1):

Error `pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results. Previous SQL was not a query` indicates syntax problem with your SQL. In this case, there are multiple DDL and DML queries that are only separated by a line terminator (`\n`).

In your case, it's best to split each statement out into a separate `cursor.execute(...)` call, ensuring you `connection.commit()` after the temporary table insert. Then execute the `select` to populate your numpy array as was previously attempted.

Comment: connection.commit() was missing for me when trying to execute an update query